# how do i retain the value of dynamically added textboxes

Tags: php, javascript, textbox

i am using this code:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Dynamic Form</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var i = 6;
    function CreateTextbox(){
      createTextbox.innerHTML = createTextbox.innerHTML 
                   +'<input type=text name="flow'+i+'"/>'
       i++;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="form" action="post">
  <input type="button" name="what" value="clickHere" onClick="CreateTextbox()"/>
   <div id="createTextbox"></div>
 </form>
</body>
```

when i add a new textbox, the value that was entered in the previous textbox is deleted. how can i retain it?

Comment: Exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391875/how-do-i-retain-the-value-of-dynamically-added-textboxes

Comment: Is this thread is duplicate or a pasted link is duplicate?

Comment: Here's the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390553/javascript-php-get-value-from-a-dynamically-added-textbox

Comment: Dude, are you even reading the answers to your previous questions? We've already told you not to use innerHTML for this several times.

Answer (score 1):

Adding HTML element by concatenating the innerHTML is very slow and that is causing the values to be cleared, since the container  (the div `createTextbox`) and all the childs are re-created on each innerHTML assignment.

I suggest you to create the input elements programmatically with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.createElement) and append the elements using to the container div using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild):

```
window.onload = function  () {

  var createTextbox = function () {
    var i = 6,
        container = document.getElementById('createTextbox');

    return function () {
      var div = document.createElement('div'),
          input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type= "text";
      input.name = "flow" + i;
      div.appendChild(input);
      container.appendChild(div);
      i++;
    }
  }();

  // event binding
  document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = createTextbox;
}
```

Check the above code working [here](http://jsbin.com/aroxo).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably forcing the browser to recreate the element when you redefine its innerHTML property, which subsequently causes you to lose its value in the process.

Can this be done with a

```
  var elem = document.createElement("input");
  someDOMElement.childNodes.add(elem);
```

combination?